# How include git branch name in apk file name automatically

Tags: android, git, gradle

I'm looking for a way to include the *git branch name* into my android apk file name upon building it.

I would like to name my apk file "ProjectName-*git branchname*.apk, automatically upon building it.
"

Example: "MyTestProject-master.apk"

I've searched online and read the gradle docs but can't find a reference to how to include the branch name into the output file name.

I know how to use gradle to construct a file name, generally speaking. I'm specifically asking about the git branch reference.

Comment: Try looking [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250257/1790644), of course, it would require some modifications.

Comment: @MattClark I don't see a reference to git branch name on that site. I know generaly how to use gradle.

Comment: Whelp, using Gradle to change the name of the file seems to me like a bulk of the work, now figure out how to get the branch name :D I was just pointing out a helpful resources because I didn't have the full answer..

Comment: @MattClark ic, understood, thanks for help

Comment: Did you check this link? May be this could help. Its about auto-versioning a build. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414399/android-gradle-dynamically-change-versionname-at-build-time</a>

Answer (score 6):

since you know how to use Gradle to construct a file name,

Here is the task to **fetch current git branch name** into your Gradle...

```
def getBranchName = { ->
    try {
        println "Task Getting Branch Name.."

        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }

        println "Git Current Branch = " + stdout.toString()

        return stdout.toString()
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        println "Exception = " + e.getMessage()
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can concatenate it with your file name.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 5):

[This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21016461/6507689) shows how to get git branch name from command line. 

Compose them to get what you need

Sharing the code to do this:

Git executable must be on your system PATH.

```
def changeApkName = { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def apk = output.outputFile;
        def newName = androidApplicationName;
        def branch = getGitRevParseInfo("--abbrev-ref");
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            newName += "-v" + variant.mergedFlavor.versionName + "-" + branch + "-release.apk";
        } else {
            newName += "-v" + variant.mergedFlavor.versionName + "-" + branch + ".apk";
        }

        if (!output.zipAlign) {
            newName = newName.replace(".apk", "-unaligned.apk");
        }
        output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);

        println 'INFO: Set outputFile to ' + output.outputFile + " for [" + output.name + "]"
    }
}

def getGitRevParseInfo(what) {
    def cmd = "git rev-parse " + what + " HEAD"
    def proc = cmd.execute()
    proc.text.trim()
}

android {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                changeApkName(variant)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe mock up an example using the two and not just links ;)